# Can't deploy laravel 5.6.7 project to a subdomain on a web server

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I keep getting 500 error when I try to access laravel application on subdomain of a web server.

I have uploaded entire laravel project into a `public_html/laravel directory`. Document root points to public_html/laravel/public.

I've added 755 permissions to bootstrap and storage directories.

Laravel version: 5.6.7, php version on my machine: 7.1.11. Web server php version 7.0

What can cause this problem? 
Differences between php versions?

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: 
Now I've changed document root to point to public_html/laravel and when I add /public i get 'no input specified' error and error log file looks like this:

Got error "Unable to open primary script: /home/user/public_html/laravel/public/index.php(no such file or directory)"

Final Edit: The problem was php version.

Comment: I have run into this before and I just added a # to comment out the multiviews: so  #Options -MultiViews -Indexes  Not saying this is the right way but it worked for me.

Comment: The Apache server can give you more than a hint at what is wrong when you see a `500 Internal Server Error` message. Please increase `LogLevel` to `debug` and add the resulting error message from the error logfile to the question.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering. I’ve edited my question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
chown -R apache:apache /home/user/public_html/laravel/
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to explain what this does and why it is helpful. Remember that ideally this will remain a signpost to a solution on the internet for years.

Answer (score 0):

It's your PHP version. Laravel 5.6 needs [PHP >= 7.1.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should update the php version to PHP>=7.0 and secondly if there is a cache problem then you must run this command `php artisan config:cache` to clear the old configuration for local server. I faced this issue alot and i hope it will help you and others who would have same issue.